# Simple network timeout in Qt(c++)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a simple network file transfer application in Qt, and I'm struggling to implement a timeout.

Basically, what I want is the following,

```
while(!AcknowledgeReceived)
{
 if(timeout)
  {
     break;
  }
}
```

Currently, timeout is changed by a Qtimer, but once the loop starts execution, it never leaves. (The Slot QTimer emits to doesn't get executed.)
I gather that this has something to do with threads, but I'm way to new at this to implement it correctly.

So my question to you is, how do I go about ensuring that the method flipping timeout is executed, or how do I get the same results with another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
QNetworkAccessManager netman;
QNetworkRequest request{url};
QNetworkReply* reply = netman.post(request, data);

while (!reply->isFinished())
{
    QThread::msleep(1);
    qApp->processEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're looping like that, the Qt main event loop will not run, as it's in the call to your function.

You either need to redesign your application to only use slots and signals, so you don't need the loop. Or you have to [process the Qt event yourself](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents).